# How to bind Kendo grid to json data using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

HI i am using kendo grid to bind data with json and angularjs
here is my code below.
this is the .cshtml page code below.

```html
<div ng-app="Sample" ng-controller="SampleController">
    <div>Products: {{products.length}}</div>
    <div kendo-grid k-data-source="products" k-selectable="'row'"
         k-pageable='{ "pageSize": 2, "refresh": true, "pageSizes": true }'
         k-columns='[
        { "field": "EmployeeKey", "title": "EmployeeId"},
        { "field": "FirstName", "title": "First Name"},
        { "field": "LastName", "title": "Last Name"},
        { "field": "DepartmentName", "title": "Department Name" },
         { "field": "EmailAddress", "title": "Email Id" }
      ]'>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('Sample', ['kendo.directives']);
    app.controller('SampleController', function ($scope, $http) {
        debugger;
        $http.get('~/api/Employee/Employee_Read').success(function (thisdata) {
           
            var myData = $.parseJSON(JSON.parse(thisdata));
            $scope.myData = myData;
        });

        $scope.filterOptions = {
            filterText: '',
            useExternalFilter: true,
        };
        });
</script>
```

and in controller which name is EmployeeController i used json data like below:

```html
public ActionResult Employee_Read ([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request )
        {
            return Json(employeeRepositary.Employees.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

This code is working fine with @HtmlKendo grid but for this i am not able to display data.
Where i am wrong??
Please help me out from here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `kendo.data.ObservableArray` for this case

```
$http.get('~/api/Employee/Employee_Read').success(function (thisdata) {       
    var myData = $.parseJSON(JSON.parse(thisdata));
    $scope.products= new kendo.data.ObservableArray(myData.Data);
});
```

Comment: Hi Dion, i used your things and updated in my code but not working.

Comment: Hi Guys i have changed something code now able to get the data but still not showing in kendo grid here is my modified code

Comment: ah that because you have use kendo DataSourceRequest and wrap your collection instead of just return your collection. I have updated my code, see if its work now..

Comment: Hi Dion i have also done something in my code so getting data but not populating in gridview now my code is bit change from previous one. you can found by this link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30840641/data-is-getting-but-not-populating-in-kendo-grid-using-angular-js"

Comment: sorry i don't have rights to edit my previous question so i posted new question.