# Data is getting but not populating in kendo grid using angular js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, kendo-ui

I am able to get the data from database but not populating in gridview.
here is my code below:

```html
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div kendo-grid k-options="gridOptions" k-rebind="gridOptions" k-pageable='{ "pageSize": 2, "refresh": true, "pageSizes": true }'></div>
</div>
<script>
    angular.module("app", ["kendo.directives"]).controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.gridOptions = {
            columns: [{ field: "EmployeeKey" }, { field: "FirstName" }],
            dataSource: {
                //schema: {
                //    data: "d"
                //},
                type: "jsonp",
                transport: {
                   
                    read: function (e) {
                        
                        $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/Employee/Employee_Read' }).
                        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                           // alert('Sucess')
                            //debugger;
                          
                           e.success(data)
                        }).
                        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                            alert('something went wrong')
                            console.log(status);
                        });
                    }
                },
                //pageSize: 5
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

and this is the controller page where i am getting data

```html
public ActionResult Employee_Read ([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request )
        {
            //IQueryable<IEmployeeRepositary> employeeRep = employeeRepositary.Employees;
            return Json(employeeRepositary.Employees.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

so after running my application i am checking through debugger this line
"e.success(data)" so in mouse hove i am getting the total records fetched from database. but not populating in gridview it is still showing blank.
please help me out from here.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are returning collection which wrapped with `DataSourceResult` method.

```
return Json(employeeRepositary.Employees.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

instead of just its collection

```
return Json(employeeRepositary.Employees, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

You need to define your data source `schema`, please try this schema setup

```
schema: {
     data: "Data",
     errors: "Errors",
     total: "Total",
     model: {
         id: "Id",
         fields: {
             Id: { editable: false, defaultValue: 0 },
             //the rest field definition
         }
     }
}
```

and you can change your transport's `read` to something like this

```
read: {
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Employee/Employee_Read",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json"
}
```

your final code should be like this

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    columns: [{ field: "EmployeeKey" }, { field: "FirstName" }],
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Employee/Employee_Read",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json"
            },
            parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                return JSON.stringify(options);
            }
        },
        pageSize: 5,
        schema: {
            data: "Data",
            errors: "Errors",
            total: "Total",
            model: {
                id: "EmployeeKey",
                fields: {
                    EmployeeKey: { editable: false, defaultValue: 0 },
                    FirstName: {type: "string", validation: { required: true }}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and your controller like this

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Employee_Read ([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request )
{
    var employees = employeeRepositary.Employees;

    return Json(employees.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Hi Dion Thanks for your reply can u make my code correct which i mentioned above with your solution because here i am not able to integrate both code schema and read in one.

Comment: Hi Dion i applied your integrated code with me but gridview is not populating i changed the code in my controller also as suggested by you but still not working can you check the same with your system??

Comment: Weird, its working at my end.. You should stick your controller code with previous one.. Don't change it just apply the schema..

Comment: Dion, i used my previous code in controller did not change anything there and used your integrated code and removed k-rebind attribute but still not showing data in gridview. even i put break point in employee_read function there break point is not firing. it means it's not getting the correct path.

Comment: is it in one domain or different? use `dataType: "jsonp"` if its in different domain, and have you add tag attribute in controller to accept HttpPost request?
add `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]` above your controller action method if its not there.

Comment: Hey thanks man it's working fine there was some js script which was not in order so i make it in orderwise and it's working fine.

Comment: Hey Dion, can u tell me one thing if i am going to bind some 400 and 500 records it's showing perfectly without paging but if record is 50000 it's not showing any data in gridview. can u tell me why it's happening??

Comment: Yeah, it a bad design tough to bring all data to client and do paging in client side (internally kendo's grid do this in client automatically), instead just bring the current page data to client (server side paging).